# How to use media queries in angular component's styles.scss?

Tags: html, css, angular, media-queries, responsive

I am trying to use media query in component's styles, but when I resize the window, nothing is happens

```
 @media query screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
/* Here are some changes*/
}
```

It doesn't work at all, do I need to load some modules or how to fix it. Any help appreciate.

Comment: You don't need any modules to import and it is nothing to do with angular as it is a pure css and **media queries** are built-in in css. See the answers below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use following syntax. This is the correct syntax for media query.
Hope this helps!!

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
    /* Here are some changes*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a useful notice to remove the 'query', also I have added the '!important' to increase the priority and it worked perfectly. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to write different media queries for each breakpoint. Also, the syntax is like below

```
    /* Tablet*/
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      /* Here are some changes*/
    }

   /* Mobile */
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
          /* Here are some changes*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `query`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) 
{
 /* Here are some changes*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler way,

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    /* Here are some changes*/
}
```